# Mapping from linear functionals to $\mathbb R^n$ is surjective

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $f$ be a linear functional from $\mathbb R ^n$ to $\mathbb R$. Then, it can be shown that $f$  has the form $f (x) = \sum_{i=1} ^n \alpha_i x(i)$, where $x(i)$'s are the coordinates of $x$. Now consider $\alpha = [\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_n] $ and the mapping $A$, which maps every $f$ to some $\alpha$. I need to show that $A$ is linear, injective, and surjective (hence an isomorphism).

The proofs to linearity and injectivity are straightforward. But, I feel uncertain how to approach subjectivity. Here is my idea. I have to show that each $\alpha$ can be written in the form of $A (f)$ for some $f$.

Let $b = [b_1, \cdots, b_n]$ be a basis for $\mathbb R^n.$ Then $f(x) = \sum _{i=1}^n f(b_i) x(i)$. That is, each $\alpha_i = f(b_i)$. Thus, $\alpha = [\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_n] = [f(b_1), \cdots, f(b_n)].$ Not sure how to continue form here onward. Is this the proper approach at all?

Or, instead should I start by parsing $f$ into independent $f_i$s, each equal to the corresponding $\alpha_i$? (How can I do that in proper formalism?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any $\alpha $ in $\mathbb R^{n}$ simply define $f$ by $f(x)=\sum \alpha_ix_i$. Verify that this is a lnear map. Now $\alpha $ is the image of this $f$.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't that be circular reasoning? I mean, this form for $f$ is given in the very description of the problem.

Comment: @Neutrino No, it is not circular.